# NameError in Machine learning with Open Data Cube notebook code

Tags: machine-learning, open-data-cube

I am trying to run the "Machine learning with the Open Data Cube" using my own .shp file but seem to keep getting the same error. The only cell that I altered in the following link is number 3, and the error then comes up after cell 9:  https://docs.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/Frequently_used_code/Machine_learning_with_ODC.html

The code works perfectly when I don't alter the shapefile path but as soon as I add my own shape file ([available here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ecipagdtyi89qws/AAD9_duez4uZyxQyuUtzz-7ka?dl=1)) it doesn't work anymore. The format of the example .shp file and mine are the same.

The code in the original tutorial for cell 3 was:

```
path = '../Supplementary_data/Machine_learning_with_ODC/example_training_data.shp'
field = 'classnum'
time = ('2015')
zonal_stats = 'median'
resolution = (-25, 25)
output_crs = 'epsg:3577'
```

I then customised that using my own shape file in cell 3:

```
path = '../Supplementary_data/Machine_learning_with_ODC/Trainingv4.shp'
field = 'classnum'
time = ('2015')
zonal_stats = 'median'
resolution = (-25, 25)
output_crs = 'epsg:4326'
```

Every other cell remained the same and the preview of my shapefile had the same format as the example one (ie class column with integer and then geometry coordinates)

[image: this is the error message that I get]

Any suggestions?

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't provide the information that you modified in the code. Can you please edit your question to show how you altered the cell 3 ? 
from what we can see on your error, the `time` lib was not imported in the file classification.py

Comment: Thanks @PierrickRambaud, I have now added the extra info, any help is appreciated

Comment: Hey @brianna! We should be able to help out with this, thanks for including the extra detail. Is there any chance you could upload your training shapefile as a .zip to something like Dropbox and include the link here? That way we can see if we can replicate it on our end.

Comment: Hello @RobbiBishop-Taylor that would be much appreciated, can access the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ecipagdtyi89qws/AAD9_duez4uZyxQyuUtzz-7ka?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

I am an author of the notebook and the classification tools library, I've fixed the issue you found. It was a missing import triggered in a particular edge case, in this instance some of your training labels fail to load data. You can access these changes by pulling down the latest [develop branch](https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-notebooks) or simply add `import time` to the `classification.py` file in DEA Tools.
I noted that your data is in CRS `EPSG:4326`, I reprojected it to albers `EPSG:3577` and was able to successfully run through the notebook and complete a classification.

Comment: Thanks Sean for your swift response. I have tried using the new code downloaded from the github site but it seems that there may be a few errors in the updated version that I am unsure how to resolve. After running the first cell (without changing anything) I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dea_classificationtools'
Even after adding import dea_classificationtools into the cell it will not run